# Django Template Variable Not Loading

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Forgive me; I am very new to Django.

In my django template, I am having trouble loading one specific variable from views (which is a string).  All my other variables are loading well and good, and I know this variable exists as "h" in the code below.  I have tested this fact and know it as a fact.  And yet, it is not displaying!

index request from views.py w/ post as the issue:

```
def index(request):
con = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
template = loader.get_template('searching/index.html')
if request.method == 'POST':
    keyword = None
    years = None
    keyword = request.POST.get("keyword")
    years = request.POST.get("year")

    if years is not None:
        years = int(years)
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM searching_insight WHERE year = ?', (years,))
        documents = cursor.fetchall()
        results = YearSearchTFIDF(years)
        script, div = YearsOnlyCharter(results, years)
    elif keyword is not None:
        keyword_for_query = "%" + keyword + "%"
        keyword_for_query = keyword_for_query.lower()
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM searching_insight WHERE body LIKE ?', (keyword_for_query,))  
        documents = cursor.fetchall()
        results = KeywordSearchTFIDF(keyword.lower())
        if results == "No results found":
            div = "<div>No results found.  Try again.</div>"
            return render(request, 'searching/index.html', {'errorsearch': "No documents found.  Please try again."})
        else:  
            ordereddict1 = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(results.items(), key = lambda t: t[0]))
            results = dict(ordereddict1)
            script, div = KeywordOnlyCharter(results, keyword)
    else:
        print("tbd")

    context = {
        'keyword':keyword,
        'years':years,
        'results': results,
        'script': script,
        'div': div,
        'documents': documents,
    }

    return render(request, 'searching/index.html', context)
else:
    return render(request, 'searching/index.html')
```

My issue in the html is at the bottom of this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
{% load convertltgt %}
{% block head %}
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="{% static "css/searching.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-1.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
    {{ script | safe }}
    <title>WW:TBHT</title>
</head>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="fab fa-pagelines"></i>  WW:TBHT</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/searching">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="/data">Data - Keywords</a></li>
        <li><a href="/graphs">Data - Graphs</a></li>
        <li><a href="/background">Background</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

    <div class="headline">
      <img class="vine_left" src="https://i.ibb.co/285jFB5/download.png">

      {% if keyword %}
          <h1>Results for "{{ keyword }}"</h1>
      {% elif years %}
        <h1>Results for {{ years }}</h1>
      {% else %}
        <h1>Search WW:TBHT</h1>
      {% endif %}

      <img class="vine_right" src="https://i.ibb.co/285jFB5/download.png">

    </div>

    {% if errorsearch %}
      <br><br><br><h3 id="errormessage"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {{ errorsearch }} </h3>
    {% endif %}

   <div id="bigtfidfgraph">
       {{ div | safe }}
   </div>

   <div id="resultsdocuments">
    {% for (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) in documents %}
      <div class="document">
        <h3 class="title">{{ b }} </h3>
        <h4 class="date"> {{ d }} </h4>
        <p class="citation"> {{ h|safe }} </p>
        <div class="text">{{ c | safe }}</div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
   </div>
```

**I have tried both |safe filter and without filter!**

The variable should load as something like:

> Howells, William Dean [unsigned in original]. "'Bardic Symbols'." 28 March 1860. The Walt Whitman Archive. Gen. ed. Ed Folsom and Kenneth M. Price. Accessed 11 April 2019. [http://www.whitmanarchive.org].

I am totally at a loss as to why this won't load; if the variable is indeed h (tested), every other variable in this for-loop prints out fine, what could be the issue?  Does it have something to do with the brackets and quotations?  I wouldn't think so.

Comment: Note: the linked text in the citation is not a link in the variable, just text in the string.

Comment: Why are you doing any of this? Why aren't you using models?

Comment: I am using models?  I don't understand the question.  The better way to phrase this for a beginner would be, "Have you looked at models yet?"

Comment: furthermore, I am using models.  The variables don't respond when I utilize .citation on the model.

Comment: And I'm not entirely sure how to utilize models when only calling certain documents from the database.  How do I let the views.py know that it's a model, not just some random junk I made up?

Comment: What Daniel is trying to say is there's no reason to use raw SQL and SQLite the way you're doing it. You should be using Django's built in ORM which uses SQLite by default. This will make it far easier displaying data in your template.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like something I definitely need to look into.